# Create ZIP file from SQL Server Varbinary column

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, .net-4.5

I am trying download multiple files using zipArchive from SQL Server database using Console application. This following code creates an empty file. It retrieves content and adds to MemoryStream.

```
SqlCommand myCommand;
SqlDataReader reader = null;

using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    string SQL = "select doc_name, doc_content from Documents where id = 200";
    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand = new SqlCommand(SQL.ToString(), myConnection);
    reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    byte[] zipBytes = null;


    using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())

    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //Create a zip entry for each attachment
            var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(reader["doc_name"].ToString());

            //Get the stream of the attachment
            using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream((byte[])reader["doc_content"]))
            using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
            {
                //Copy the attachment stream to the zip entry stream
                originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
            }
        }

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\test\test.zip", FileMode.Create))
        {
            compressedFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            compressedFileStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: At the time you read from `compressedFileStream`, you haven't yet closed/disposed `zipArchive`, which means there's no guarantees that it has done *anything* much yet. You should rework it such that you only attempt to read from `compressedFileStream` *after* fully disposing `zipArchive`.

Comment: Side note: if the doc is large, it would be an idea to use the streaming reader API, not just reading it as a `byte[]` - that is more complex, though, and requires you use for forwards-only flag

Comment: I don't get where the question is...